# How to specify the caption names in bilingual captions without babel or polyglossia?

Tags: captions, languages, naming

I use [Axel Sommerfeldt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2574/axel-sommerfeldt)'s [bicaption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package to setup bilingual captions. 
`bicaption` needs `babel`'s `\selectlanguage` to set the different caption names for different languages. However, I cannot use the faculty of `babel`/`polyglossia` since it doesn't work for east Asian languages.

It is easy to set a `name` option for the two captions, but I can't set different names for different types of floats. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}[2012/02/19 v3.2f]
\usepackage{bicaption}[2011/10/30 v1.0a]
\captionsetup[bi-first]{name=Foo}
\captionsetup[bi-second]{name=Bar}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering FIGURE
  \bicaption{XXX}{YYY}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering TABLE
  \bicaption{XXX}{YYY}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I tried

```
\captionsetup[bi-first,figure]{name=Foo}
```

there's no effect. And I tried

```
\captionsetup[bi-first]{figurename=Foo}
```

then I got an error

> `! Package caption Error: Can be used only in preamble.`

So what can I do? Is there a simple way to use `bicaption` without `babel`?

In an older version of `caption` package (e.g. 2011/11/10 v3.2e), `figurename` and `table` options can be used in `document` environment, but the latest `caption` allows them only to be used in the preamble. I cannot see any advantage to set `\@onlypreamble\caption@SetName`. However, even if I use the old version of `caption`, I still cannot set the name for user-defined (via `newfloat` package) floats in bilingual captions.

---

Note: I do not like the `\bicaption` provided by `ccaption` package, it is complicated to use. And I have the ability to define my own version of `\bicaption`, but it seems also a bad option.

Currently I can use this weird trick:

```
\captionsetup[bi-first]{font=bi-first}
\captionsetup[bi-second]{font=bi-second}
\DeclareCaptionFont{bi-first}{%
  \def\tablename{Table}%
  \def\figurename{Figure}}
\DeclareCaptionFont{bi-second}{%
  \def\tablename{Alter-table}%
  \def\figurename{Alter-figure}}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IMHO your trick is fine, if you want to make it looking a little bit less weird you could use `\DeclareCaptionOption` instead of `\DeclareCaptionFont`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}[2012/02/19 v3.2f]
\usepackage{bicaption}[2011/10/30 v1.0a]

\captionsetup[bi-first]{bi-first}
\captionsetup[bi-second]{bi-second}

\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-first}[]{%
  \def\tablename{Table}%
  \def\figurename{Figure}}
\DeclareCaptionOption{bi-second}[]{%
  \def\tablename{Alter-table}%
  \def\figurename{Alter-figure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering FIGURE
  \bicaption{XXX}{YYY}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering TABLE
  \bicaption{XXX}{YYY}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

However, I think a dedicated interface for usage of `bicaption` without `babel/polyglossia` would be great, so I will design it in the next days... (Please stay tuned.)

(2012-04-09) ...done. I have added a small interface for using the `lang=` option without `babel/polyglossia` in the upcoming version 1.1 of the `bicaption` package, so the example above could also be written as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}[2012/03/25 v3.3]
\usepackage{bicaption}[2012/04/09 v1.1]

\captionsetup[bi-first]{lang=first}
\captionsetup[bi-second]{lang=second}

\renewcommand\selectcaptionlanguage[2]{%
  \csname select#2language\endcsname}
\newcommand\selectfirstlanguage{%
  \def\tablename{Table}%
  \def\figurename{Figure}}
\newcommand\selectsecondlanguage{%
  \def\tablename{Alter-table}%
  \def\figurename{Alter-figure}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering FIGURE
  \bicaption{XXX}{YYY}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering TABLE
  \bicaption{XXX}{YYY}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Furthermore I have implemented `\captionsetup[figure][bi-first]{name=Foo}` in the upcoming version 3.3 of the `caption` package, so an alternative implementation would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}[2012/03/25 v3.3]
\usepackage{bicaption}[2012/04/09 v1.1]

\captionsetup[figure][bi-first]{name=Figure}
\captionsetup[figure][bi-second]{name=Alter-figure}

\captionsetup[table][bi-first]{name=Table}
\captionsetup[table][bi-second]{name=Alter-table}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering FIGURE
  \bicaption{XXX}{YYY}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
  \centering TABLE
  \bicaption{XXX}{YYY}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'll release both of them within the next weeks.

Regarding the `figurename` option: This option was designed for usage with `babel/polyglossia`, therefore it could have caused trouble when used within the document text. And since it was never documented for usage within the document text I have added the `\@onlypreamble` stuff.

Comment: Thank you. `\DeclareCaptionOption` is  better. And I'm glad that there would be a new interface for this.

Comment: And, why not use `\DeclareCaptionOptionNoValue`? I wonder why it is not documented either.

Comment: `\DeclareCaptionOptionNoValue` will be fine, too. Unfortunately the `caption` package documentation is currently not up-to-date, that's the only reason why it's not documented yet.

Comment: Just a short note that I've added a paragraph about the upcoming version 1.1 of the `bicaption` package. If you have further ideas on how to improve usage without babel/polyglossia please don't hesitate to contact me.