# pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figure.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, captions, warnings, cjk

I've tried to make bilingual caption with package "ccaption" and compiled it with pdfLaTeX.

It works fine but with a warning:

> pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{figure.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored.

Here is a mini example:

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}                 
\usepackage{graphicx}               
\usepackage{ccaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Figure \ref{fig1}
\begin{figure}
\bicaption[fig1]{}{中文标题}{Fig.}{English caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Sorry for the inconvenience if you don't have package **ctex** which defines a documents class **ctexart** for typesetting Chinese. You can replace the `documentclass` with `article` and the warning it still there.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek :) Thanks. I've got a lot help from TeX.SX. This is my very first time to register and ask a question.

Comment: Warning, here comes an absolute shameless self-advertisement: The `bicaption` package works fine with `hyperref`, out-of-the-box.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Sure it is. Maybe you could consider adding the first example from your answer [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51058/how-to-specify-the-caption-names-in-bilingual-captions-without-babel-or-polyglos/51066#51066) to the manual, which I believe is easier to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`ccaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ccaption) uses an elementary (and mostly feasible) way of producing duplicate captions for the same float. The main function at play here is `\contcaption`:

```
\newcommand{\contcaption}{%
  \addtocounter{\@captype}{\m@ne}%
  \refstepcounter{\@captype}%
  \@contcaption\@captype}
```

It steps the regular float counter back by one, sets a reference and then continues a call to set the actual caption text. On the `.aux`-file side, this leads to two cross-reference entries with the same hyperlink anchor name... something that [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) doesn't enjoy. True, without `hyperref`, this problem won't be noticeable.

A way around this is to use an alias counter, provided by the [`aliascnt` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/aliascnt), and using it as part of `\contcaption`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexart}
\usepackage{aliascnt,ccaption}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{aliascnt,ccaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref

\newaliascnt{figurealt}{figure}% New alias counter for figure float
\aliascntresetthe{figurealt}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\contcaption}{%
  \expandafter\addtocounter\expandafter{\@captype alt}{\m@ne}% Step alias cntr back
  \expandafter\refstepcounter\expandafter{\@captype alt}% Make reference
  \@contcaption\@captype}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Figures~\ref{fig1} and~\ref{fig2}.
\begin{figure}
\bicaption[fig1]{}{abc}{Fig.}{English caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\bicaption[fig2]{}{xyz}{Fig.}{English caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The above MWE provides the alias `figurealt` which should work in tandem with `figure`, using *it* as the replacement reference for the second (continued) caption rather than the traditional float counter.

A similar alias can be created for other floats (like `table`, using `tablealt`).

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your quick response, though the solution is a little bit complicated than I thought. It works perfect.